# Workwflow delete action

Tags: liferay, workflow

I'm using Liferay 7.2.

I create a workflow for web content.

It works for update action, it is possibile add the "delete" action to workflow?

I don't want that a user can delete a pdf file without approval

Comment: Good point. Delete is a different kind of update, but maybe it's not trapped by workflow...

Comment: Please [note the crossposting netiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824)

Comment: ok, i think a solution can be a listener